# How to implement page turner buttons in QML swipeview

Tags: qml, qtquick2, swipeview, qtquickcontrols2

I have to implement pages using QML component like Item (say Item 1, Item 2, Item 3) in SwipeView without using Repeaters and also implement page turners as shown below. The getPreviousPage Rectangle should move the view to turn to previous page similarly for getNextPage Rectangle.

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

Window {
  visible: true
  color:"black"
  width: 400+100
  height: 200

  Rectangle
  {
      id:getPreviousPage
      color:"red"
      x:0
      y:0
      width:50
      height:200
      MouseArea
      {
          anchors.fill:parent
          onClicked:
          {
              //turn to previous page
          }
      }
  }

  Rectangle
  {
      id:getNextPage
      color:"green"
      width:50
      x:450
      y:0
      height:200
      MouseArea
      {
          anchors.fill:parent
          onClicked:
          {
              //turn to next page
          }
      }
  }




  Pane {
      id: pane
      width: 400
      height: 200
      x:50
      y:0

      SwipeView {
          id: view
          currentIndex: 1
          anchors.fill: parent

          Repeater {
              model: 3

              Pane {
                  width: view.width
                  height: view.height

                  Column {
                      spacing: 40
                      width: parent.width

                      Label {
                          width: parent.width
                          wrapMode: Label.Wrap
                          horizontalAlignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
                          text: view.currentIndex
                      }


                  }
              }
          }
      }


  }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 200
    height: 400
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    id: page

    SwipeView {
        id: swipeView
        anchors.fill: parent
        currentIndex: 0
        Page {
                    Label {
                        text: qsTr("First page")
                        anchors.centerIn: parent
                    }
                }
        Page {
                    Label {
                        text: qsTr("Second page")
                        anchors.centerIn: parent
                    }
                }
        Page {
                    Label {
                        text: qsTr("Third page")
                        anchors.centerIn: parent
                    }
                }
        Page {
                    Label {
                        text: qsTr("Fourth page")
                        anchors.centerIn: parent
                    }
                }
        Page {
                    Label {
                        text: qsTr("Fifth page")
                        anchors.centerIn: parent
                    }
                }
    }



    Rectangle
    {
        id:minus
        width:parent.width/2
        height:100
        anchors.left:parent.left
        anchors.bottom:parent.bottom
        color:"red"
        MouseArea
        {
            anchors.fill:parent
            onClicked:{
                if(swipeView.currentIndex>0)
                    swipeView.currentIndex--
            }
        }
    }
    Rectangle
    {
        id:plus
        width:parent.width/2
        height:100
        anchors.right:parent.right
        anchors.bottom:parent.bottom
        color:"green"
        MouseArea
        {
            anchors.fill:parent
            onClicked:{
                if(swipeView.currentIndex<4)
                    swipeView.currentIndex++
            }
        }
    }


}
```

You can just use Page Qml types instead of Repeaters. Above given code has sample implementation of Page Turners.

Comment: Since Qt Quick Controls 2.1 (Qt 5.8) SwipeView has also incrementCurrentIndex() and decrementCurrentIndex() for convenience (and to avoid breaking existing bindings).